# Is there a way to add data to a Response object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to subclass a view from a third party library, by calling `super` and then adding some extra data to the [`Response` object](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/) from `django-rest-framework`. However, I'm not sure how that can be done, as all examples show data being wrapped in the `Response` object only on instantiation.

If further context is needed: I'm trying to do so with the `ObtainJSONWebToken` view of `django-rest-framework-jwt`, in an effort to add user data. Right now the Response that view adds only contains the JWT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this can easily be done using `Response.data`

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response =  super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.data['first_name'] = "John"
        response.data['last_name'] = "Doe"
        return response
```

Comment: Now Django response seems remove data attribute? The only thing we can access is response.content where it's a byte object? Is there any update?